# 2 arrays in javascript. One inherits another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var t1 = [2,4,7,9];
var t2 = t1;
console.warn(t2); // [2, 4, 7, 9]
t1[1] = 7;
console.warn(t2); // [2, 7, 7, 9]
```

Why? :) I can't understand. t2 is inheits t1?

Comment: Arrays are passed as "reference of a value", see the duplicate for a much longer explanation, and that's why you're working with the same array in both variables, and not unique arrays.

Comment: To solve the issue for you, if you want to copy the array, you can do `var t2 = t1.slice();`